# How can I create an array of classes in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, class

I have various classes and was wondering how to create an array of classes so I can run them simultaneously

Comment: Could you give more specific please?

Comment: Technically it wont be simultaneously.

Comment: What do you mean by **so I can run them simultaneously**?

Comment: "How do I use a ruler to drill square holes?"

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
Class[] classes = new Class[] {Class1.class, Class2.class};
```

Though I'm not quite sure what your question is...